# Setting up a replicated database

Tags: java, database

I am new to the concept of Replicated Database. I wanted to set up a peer-to-peer network of 2-3 computers so that I would be able to query any of the computer to get the result. Please could anyone guide me from where should I start learning the programming related to this topic.

Comment: Database replication is provided 100% by the database. It has nothing to do with Java or programming.

Comment: Sorry that I tagged the problem with mysql.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start with theory:

[Amazon Dynamo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_%28storage_system%29)

Then there's quite a big list of [distributed stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_data_store)

Comment: It's hard to see how any of this answers a question tagged MySQL, not that it's on-topic anyway.

Comment: It was tagged mysql by mistake it seems? "Sorry that I tagged the problem with mysql. –  user3327899"